# Using a .desktop file to launch a node.js app

Tags: bash, .desktop, nodejs

In Ubuntu 16.04, I (eventually) want to drop a text file onto a desktop icon and get a Node.js app to run, treating the dropped file and outputting a new file.

I have discovered `.desktop` files, and am doing my best to understand how to get the process to work, using a barebones set-up. I currently have three files: two files in a directory at `/home/blackslate/Utilities/` and one on my desktop.

**Utilities files**

A text file named `convert.js`:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const random = crypto.randomBytes(4).toString('hex');
const filename = random + '.txt'

fs.appendFile(filename, 'Hello ' + random + '!', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(filename + ' saved');
});
```

An executable file named `convert.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
node ./convert.js

gnome-terminal -e "bash -c 'echo hello world; sleep 3'"
```

**Desktop file**

An executable file named `convert.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=gnome-terminal -e "/home/blackslate/Utilities/convert.sh \"%u\""
Icon=utilities-terminal
Type=Application
Name=Convert
```

Here's what happens:

1. If I call `node ./convert.js` from a Terminal window, I see that:

   - A new file is created and its name is shown in the Terminal window
2. If I call `./convert.sh` from a Terminal window, I see that:

   - A new file is created and its name is shown in the same Terminal window
   - A second Terminal window is opened and says `hello world` before closing 3 seconds later
3. If I click on the Convert desktop file, I see that:

   - One Terminal window opens, showing a bunch of text, and then it closes immediately
   - A second Terminal window is opened and says `hello world` before closing 3 seconds later
   - No new text file is created

It is obvious that the second command in the `convert.sh` file is being executed, but it appears that something is going wrong with the first one. What steps can I take to debug and fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A .desktop can easily run a bash script

You should change things in your `convert.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash
# set prompt to the working dir with cd
cd /home/blackslate/Utilities/
node ./convert.js

# You want some text notification? Use notify-send
notify-send -t 3000 'echo hello world'
```

Note that you can redirect the output of node ./convert.js to a variable and use it as notification text...
`MYVAR=$(node ./convert.js)` then `notify-send -t 3000 "Convert" "$MYVAR"`

And you may make some changes in the `.desktop` file
*find icons there `/usr/share/icons`*

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec='/home/blackslate/Utilities/convert.sh'
Name=Convert
Icon=utilities-terminal
```

Comment: you should also explain that .Desktop files don't include exported variables from .bashrc or other that he might be expecting and will therefore have to preemptively re-export as part of the exec commands.

Comment: Thanks @cmak.fr! Your input has helped me get the whole process working. Now I will have time to explore the new concepts that you have introduced me to.